# Why was Indra afraid of Himalaya's devotion to Shiva?

Tags: shiva, indra, shiva-purana

Was there a reason Indra being afraid of Himalaya's devotion to Shiva ?

Comment: But Himalya is devotee of Vishnu, not of Shiva. Actually they didn't had a bit of faith in Shiva until Parvati married Shiva.

Comment: This is false, Himalaya at one point had a lot of faith and devotion in Shiva, this is why Indra was afraid that Shiva will be impressed and will give a boon to Himalaya which may result in Indra's lose, I need an elaborate answer please

Comment: Are your first and second questions related? If not, you can separate 2nd question. As far as i know, 1st question is not related to 2nd question.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Providing a reference to context will improve your question.